# How large must the Quantum teleportation fidelity have to be in order for it to be useful?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, atoms, molecules, quantum-teleportation

This question relates and stems from my original question. Please read this one and the comments before answering this question.
[Quantum Teleportation Fidelity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55380/quantum-teleportation-fidelity)

I know that for discrete variables quantum teleportation, one needs a fidelity greater than 50%, otherwise you could produce that state by classical means. For continuous variables quantum teleportation, it needs to be greater than 75% for the same reason as discrete variables.

Many experiments have shown quantum teleportation in discrete and continuous variables cases, but how large must the fidelity need to be in order for it to be considered "useful"? Does it depend on application?

Moreover, let me offer an example:
If the "exact" quantum state of a physical system was transferred to another physical system, where the two physical systems were made out of the same particles, then it wouldn't it mean that it is "as if" the original object disappeared from one location and reappeared at another? My understanding and reasoning is that since the quantum state of a physical system is literally the only thing that allows us to distinguish quantum systems from each other, then if the quantum state is teleported to from one physical system to another physical system that's made up of the same particles, the physical system literally "becomes" the object.

Branching from this, say you had 97% fidelity in teleporting the vibrational state of a diatomic molecule to another diatomic molecule. Since quantum states change all the time due to constant interactions from the environment, then transferring 97% of the the original quantum state would basically give you the real system because it too would be subjected to tons of interactions right after the transfer. What I'm saying is that comparing a 100% transfer fidelity scenario to a 97% scenario, you'd end up with the diatomic molecule basically behaving in the same way as the original because there's so many interactions that would mess up the state anyway. So, is this valid in saying that its still useful to teleport, even if technically the quantum state is not the same, but its "effectively" the same?